# Trigger media queries using javascript

Tags: javascript, media-queries

Is it possible to trigger `@media all and (max-width: 960px)` from javascript without re-sizing the browser?

Comment: It seems possible to *add* a media query rule (which is in my (deleted) answer), but I think the media-conditional rules themselves can't be triggered unless they're matched by the user-agent in question.

Comment: @JanDvorak The designer at our team changed the sidebar from 'user-responsive' to 'toggle user-responsive'. That's why.